# Split list into lists containing only 1s

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, grouping

I have this list in python:

```
[100, 96, 1, 1, 1, 2, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 55, 1]
```

How could I split the given list (and other lists containing 1s) so that I get sub-lists containing only neighbouring 1s - so the result would be:

```
   [ [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1], [1] ]
```

I guess I am looking to build a function that would somehow detect the "outer" 1s as the points of list separation:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perfect case [for `itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
from itertools import groupby

inputlist = [100, 96, 1, 1, 1, 2, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 55, 1]

result = [list(grp) for val, grp in groupby(inputlist) if val == 1]
```

`groupby` without a key just groups up runs of the same value, yielding one copy of the value and an iterator of that run of values on each loop. You check if this is a run of `1`s (discarding any groups that aren't), and if it is, listify the group to make the next sub-`list`.

Answer (score 3):

I guess there could be an approach using maybe `itertools`' `takewhile`/`dropwhile` or something, but this simple for loop does it:

```
l = [100, 96, 1, 1, 1, 2, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 55, 1]

res = []
tmp = []

for i in l:
  if i == 1:
    tmp.append(i)
  elif tmp:
    res.append(tmp)
    tmp = []

if tmp:
  res.append(tmp)

print(res)
```

Output:

```
[[1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1], [1]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
def get_one_lists(the_list):
    result = []                        # Initialize list of lists
    among_ones = False                 # Flag whether we are now among 1's
    for e in the_list:
        if e == 1:
            if among_ones:
                result[-1].append(1)   # Already among 1's. Append this 1 too.
            else:
                result.append([1])     # Stumbled upon a new sequence of 1's
                among_ones = True
        else:
            among_ones = False
    return result
```

**Testing:**

```
my_list = [100, 96, 1, 1, 1, 2, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 55, 1]
print(get_one_lists(my_list))
my_list = [1, 100, 96, 1, 1, 1, 2, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 55, 1]
print(get_one_lists(my_list))
```

**Output:**

```
[[1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1], [1]]
[[1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1], [1]]
```